# Feeding MPAndroid Bar Chart with data from an array

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mpandroidchart

I am fetching data from firebase with this method:

```js
        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference eventIdRef = rootRef.child("points");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>();
                List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final String Sname = ds.child("symptomName").getValue(String.class);
                    final Integer counter = ds.child("patientsCounter").getValue(Integer.class);
                    
                    count.add(counter);
                    names.add(Sname);
                   
                    DataPoint dataPoint = ds.getValue(DataPoint.class);
                    dataValues1(count , Sname);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        eventIdRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The data from firebase (symptomName and counter) is supposed to plot a bar chart using MPAndroidChart as x and y axis respectively. I have this but it's not working :

```js
        barChart = findViewById(R.id.mp_BarChart);
        BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet((Sname, counter), "Dataset 1");
        barDataSet1.addColor(Color.BLUE);
        BarData barData = new BarData();
        barData.addDataSet(barDataSet1);
        barChart.setData(barData);
        barChart.invalidate();
```

Is it possible to pass the data from firebase directly to the chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before this line:

```
BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet((Sname, counter), "Dataset 1");
```

You need to add:

```
BarEntries barEntries = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
barEntries.add(new BarEntry(names[i], counter[i]));
}
```

Then you need to replace this line:

```
BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet((Sname, counter), "Dataset 1");
```

with this line:

```
BarDataSet barDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(barEntries, "Dataset 1");
```

Comment: I hope this will solve your problem. Do let me know if you need more help. Happy Coding :)